# relative path traversing, is this valid?

Tags: path, relative-path, traversal

I have a an XML file where I need to get up 2 dirs to get a file (from water to fire)

```
<album basepath="albums/water/images">
    <img src="001.jpg" />
    <img src="002.jpg" />
    <img src="../../fire/images/005.jpg" />
</album>
```

So my question is if

```
albums/water/images/../../fire/images/005.jpg
```

is a valid path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a valid path